how to use a third party codebase in heroku application
I'm trying to use the following code in my node js/react application https://github.com/elhadjaoui/Summarizeanything
I would like to add it under another subdomain. How can I do this?
Here's my package.json for my node js application
 "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js",
    "server": "node index.js",
    "client": "npm start --prefix client",
    "dev:build-server": "NODE_ENV=development webpack --config webpack.server.js --mode=development -w",
    "dev:start": "nodemon ./index.js",
    "dev": "concurrently \"npm run server\" \"npm run client\"",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "heroku-postbuild": "npm install --prefix client && npm run build --prefix client"
  },

I already have a react js application under the directory client. I would like to add the summarizeanything under the directory "ai" and have it accessed under a subdomain.
